# Is there a design pattern that supports injections of several abstract class implementations and conditionally uses one of the injected beans

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am on a project using Java and Spring Boot that processes several different message types from the same queue. Each message gets processed conditionally based on the message type, using an implementation of `MessageProcessingService` abstract class for each message type.

As of now, we have 5 different message types coming into the same consumer.  We are using the same queue because we leverage group policies in JMS, and each message type has the same business key as the group policy.

So what we end up with is that every time a requirement requires receiving a new message type, we add a new implementation of a `MessageProcessingService` and another dependency to the consumer object.  I want to find a better strategy to selectively choose the message processing

Here is an example similar to what we are doing. I do not guarantee the syntax is compilable or syntactically perfect, just demonstrating the problem. Notice all the messages resolve around a person

Consumer:

```java
@Component
public class PersonMessageConsumer {
  private MessageProcessingService<HeightUpdate> heightUpdateMessageProcessingService;
  private MessageProcessingService<WeightUpdate> weightUpdateMessageProcessingService;
  private MessageProcessingService<NameUpdate>   nameUpdateMessageProcessingService;
  private MessageProcessingService<ShowSizeUpdate> shoeSizeUpdateMessageProcessingService;

  public PersonMessageConsumer(
         MessageProcessingService<HeightUpdate> heightUpdateMessageProcessingService,
         MessageProcessingService<WeightUpdate> weightUpdateMessageProcessingService,
         MessageProcessingService<NameUpdate>   nameUpdateMessageProcessingService,
         MessageProcessingService<ShowSizeUpdate> shoeSizeUpdateMessageProcessingService) {

    this.heightUpdateMessageProcessingService = heightUpdateMessageProcessingService;
    this.weightUpdateMessageProcessingService = weightUpdateMessageProcessingService;
    this.nameUpdateMessageProcessingService = nameUpdateMessageProcessingService;
    this.shoeSizeUpdateMessageProcessingService = shoeSizeUpdateMessageProcessingService;
  }

  @JmsListener(destination = "${queueName}")
  public void receiveMessage(TextMessage message) {
    String messageType = message.getHeader("MessageType");
    switch (messageType) {
      case "HeightUpdate":
        heightUpdateMessageProcessingService.processMessage(message.getText());
        return;
      case "WeightUpdate":
        weightUpdateMessageProcessingServivce.processMessage(message.getText());
        return;
      // And other message types
      default: 
        throw new UnknownMessageTypeException(messageType);
  }
}
```

Message POJO example

```java
public class HeightUpdate implements PersonMessage {
  @Getter
  @Setter
  private int height;
}
```

PersonMessage interface

```java
public interface PersonMessage {
  int getPersonId();
}
```

MessageProcessingService

```java
public abstract class MessageProcessingService<T extends PersonMessage> {

  public void processMessage(String messageText) {
    //Common message processing, we do some more involved work here but just as a simple example
    T message = new ObjectMapper.readValue(messageText, getClassType());

    Person person = personRepository.load(message.getPersonId());
    Person originalPerson = person.deepCopy();
    processMessageLogic(person, message);

    if (originalPerson.isDifferentFrom(person)) { 
      personRespository.update(person);
    } 
  }

  protected abstract void processMessageLogic(Person person, T message);

  protected abstract Class getClassType();
}
```

Abstract class implementation example

```java
@Service("heightUpdateMessageProcessingService")
public class HeightUpdateMessageProcessingService extends MessageProcessingService<HeightUpdate> {
  @Override
  protected void processMessageLogic(Person person, HeightUpdate update) {
    person.setHeight(update.getHeight());
  }

  @Override
  protected Class getMessageType() {
    return HeightUpdate.getClass();
  }
}
```

So my question is whether or not there is a better design pattern or way of coding this in java and spring that is a little easier to clean and maintain and keeps SOLID principles in mind

Comment: Factory? Abstract Factory? NB Your code doesn't compile. There are no abstract classes here, although there should be.

Comment: Whoops, MessageProcessingService should be abstract.  The edit should be made now

Comment: Also please note that I stated `I do not guarantee the syntax is compilable or syntactically perfect, just demonstrating the problem`... I do not guarantee or even necessarily expect this code to compile, that is not a requirement of posting a question. I am demonstrating the issue I want to solve only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Add an abstract method in the `MessageProcessingService` to return the `messageType` that each concrete implementation can handle.
2. Rather than wiring each individual service into `PersonMessageConsumer`, wire in a `List<MessageProcessingService>` so that you get all of them at once.
3. Transform that `List` into a `Map<String, MessageProcessingService>`, using the `messageType` as the key.
4. Replace the `switch` statement by looking up the appropriate service in the `Map` and then invoking its `processMessage` method.

In the future you can add new instances of `MessageProcessingService` without having to edit `PersonMessageConsumer` because Spring will automatically add those new instances to the `List<MessageProcessingService>` that you wire in.